# Share Azure SQL Data with external user

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sql-database

We have implemented a data mart in Azure VM SQL Server. We transfer data to the Azure VM data from an on-prem database using the Azure Data Factory. We now need to share this data with third parties. These third party users will also need to authenticated before data can access data. How can this be accomplished in Azure ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would Service Fabric be required to share your data? Not sure what you're asking. Are you talking about setting up a new user in the database? Are you talking about staging some type of API? Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to share the database directly with external users, I would recommend putting a service layer in between.

The easiest and fastest way is to use WCF Data Services to generate an OData end point which will enable your external users to access everything in the database with the option to authenticate them through either forms based or claim based authentication.

Comment: Thx Haitham. The idea is to use another Azure service to provide data to third parties. Are you suggesting WCF Relay + OData is the way to go ?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest exposing the database directly to any other application except for your own app, you have to be selective and authenticate the users. You can do that with any web service that exposes a REST end point. OData is the easiest way to go